# Using enum property as ormlite column value instead of ordinal. is it possible?

Tags: android, ormlite

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.ENUM_STRING,columnName=TIPO_FIELD_NAME)
private TipoPedido tipo;

public enum TipoPedido {
    REGISTARNOTIFICACAORESPOSTA("Registar Notificação Resposta",SIGLA_TIPO_REGISTARNOTIFICATIORESPOSTA);

    private String tipoName;


    private String tipoValue;

    TipoPedido(String tipoName,String tipoValue){
        this.tipoName=tipoName;
        this.tipoValue=tipoValue;
    }

    public String getTipoName(){
        return tipoName;
    }

    public String getTipoValue(){
        return tipoValue;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to use the tipoValue enum property as the value for the column instead of the ordinal?

Edit:here's what i did:

Created the MyEnumPersister class:

```
public class MyEnumPersister extends EnumStringType{

private static final MyEnumPersister singleTon = new MyEnumPersister();

/**
 * @param sqlType
 * @param classes
 */
protected MyEnumPersister() {

    super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[] { Enum.class });
}

public static MyEnumPersister getSingleton() {
    return singleTon;
}


@Override
public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object obj) {

    return ((EstadoPedido)obj).getEstadoValue();
}


@Override
public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos)
        throws SQLException {

    return PedidoDTO.siglaEstadoPedidoComparator((String)sqlArg);

}
```

}

In javatoSqlArg i return directly the string corresponding to the estadoValue by using the getter inside the Enum.
I assume to get it back to a Enum from the DataBase i will need to implement the sqlArgToJava method too, but i'm yet to build it.

edit2: Seems that when i do a query on the table that holds the data, the method javaToSqlArg gets called before the sqlArgToJava, why??? here's the query:

```
public List<PedidoDTO> getPendingRequests(){

    List<PedidoDTO> pendingReq=null;
    QueryBuilder<PedidoDTO, Integer> queryBuild=null;

    try {
        queryBuild=getHelper().getPedidosDao().queryBuilder();
        pendingReq=queryBuild.where().eq(PedidoDTO.ESTADO_FIELD_NAME, PedidoDTO.SIGLA_ESTADO_PENDENTE).query();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return pendingReq;
}
```

The obj value appears as "P" which was what i convert to sql when i inserted it in the Database. Doesnt make too much sense....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default ORMLite stores the string name of the enumerated type -- in your case it would store `REGISTARNOTIFICACAORESPOSTA`.  You can override this behavior and store the ordinal value by using the `ENUM_INTEGER` data-type:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.ENUM_INTEGER)
private TipoPedido tipo;
```

This will store the `integer` ordinal value in the database instead of the string.  To quote the docs:

> The string name is the default (and recommended over `ENUM_INTEGER`) because it allows you to add additional enums anywhere in the list without worrying about having to convert data later.

However, it seems like you want to store the `tipoValue` string from the enum instead.  To do this you are doing to have to register a custom persister instead.  See the docs about this:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister

This allows you to define specifically how you want to translate the Java field into the database representation, and vice versa.   The two important methods are:

- [`javaToSqlArg(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/FieldConverter.html#javaToSqlArg%28com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType,%20java.lang.Object%29) which converts from the Java into the database format and
- [`sqlArgToJava(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/FieldConverter.html#sqlArgToJava%28com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29) which converts from the database back into Java.

You can extend [`BaseDataType`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/BaseDataType.html) and build the converter from the ground up or you can extend [`EnumStringType`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/EnumStringType.html) or [`StringType`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/StringType.html) and just override the above important methods.

Comment: Hi there Gray, I createad a class that extends EnumStringType but i'm a bit confused to which method should i use for this: resultToSqlArg() or javaToSqlArg(), which method is used to get the value from properties?

Comment: You code looks good @Max but in your `sqlArgToJava(...)` method, you are going to have to convert from the `getEstadoValue()`, which I assume is a String, to your `TipoPedido`.  I think you need a `static` method on your enum to do that mapping.

Comment: Hi! Gray, yep i already did something similar to what you're saying, i'll post tomorrow morning, so that maybe someone might need it too.

Comment: I just created a new question of the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `Enum.name()` method to fill in Db columns and `Enum.valueOf()` to parse the value back.  IMHO, I think the oridinals should never be used.

Also, you might want to take a look at this with regards to storing labels for enumeration values:

[Is there an Enum string resource lookup pattern for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742050/is-there-an-enum-string-resource-lookup-pattern-for-android)**strong text**

Comment: I meant the literal name...when i go check the tipo column the value is REGISTARNOTIFICACAORESPOSTA, but i would like it to be the tipoValue one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean then.  I thought you wanted REGISTARNOTIFICACAORESPOSTA.name().